# Environment variables not defined in SSH AuthorizedKeysCommand (Docker)

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, ldap, sshd

I'm trying to make the private key SSH connection with LDAP.

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```sh
AuthorizedKeysCommand /etc/ldap_ssh_authorized_keys.sh
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

Script to get public keys from LDAP server

**/etc/ldap_ssh_authorized_keys.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
USERSLIST=$( ldapsearch -x -D "${LDAP_USER}" -w "${LDAP_PASSWORD}" -H $LDAP_URI -b "${LDAP_BASEDN}" -s sub '(objectClass=posixAccount)' -u 'uid' \
    grep '^uid:' | sed -n '/^ /{H;d};/uid:/x;$g;s/\n *//g;s/uid: //gp'  \
)
while IFS= read -r line; do
        exists=$(ldapsearch -x -D "${LDAP_USER}" -w "${LDAP_PASSWORD}" -H $LDAP_URI -b "${LDAP_BASEDN}" \
        -s sub "(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(cn=sysadmin)(memberUid=${line}))" | grep "^# numEntries:")
        if [[ ! -z $exists ]]
        then
            ldapsearch -x -D "${LDAP_USER}" -w "${LDAP_PASSWORD}" -H $LDAP_URI -b "${LDAP_BASEDN}" \
                  -s sub "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=${line}))" \
                  -u 'sshPublicKey' \
            | sed -n '/^ /{H;d};/sshPublicKey:/x;$g;s/\n *//g;s/sshPublicKey: //gp'
           echo -e "";

        fi;
done <<< "$USERSLIST"
```

When I'm running script with /bin/bash it's working well and return my public keys.

All environment variables defined normally.

- LDAP_URI
- LDAP_BASEDN
- LDAP_USER
- LDAP_PASSWORD

The script also running normally when trying to make an SSH connection. But environment variables not available.

I'm trying also with **AuthorizedKeysCommandUser** as root. But nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by getting the environment variables from /proc/1/environ.

[Reference](https://developpaper.com/use-of-environment-variables-in-docker-and-solutions-to-common-problems/)